# What are differences between server side rendering and client side rendering in JSS?

Tags: jss, presentation

Please illuminate main differences between server side rendering and client side rendering for JSS app?

Is server side rendering only required for things which are tightly couple with Sitecore like `Experience Editor` to use through JSS app?

What are the use cases to use both type of renderings?

Comment: Server side rendering: Server-side JavaScript rendering enables execution of the same JS application you run in dev but now within Content Management environment running full Sitecore instance. In this case you will be hitting app with-in Sitecore instance. In other case "Client Side Rederning", app will be running in the node js server context not Sitecore context.

Comment: See https://medium.freecodecamp.org/server-side-rendering-your-react-app-in-three-simple-steps-7a82b95db82e in addition SSR also hides your business logic, endpoint, config from the end user. which is create for security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am new in JSS world, trying to jump into JSS pond.

## Below are differences:

**Client-side rendering-** your browser downloads a minimal HTML page. It renders the JavaScript and fills the content into it.

Rendering performed by the browser.

Data comes from Sitecore via `LayoutService/DictionaryService/GraphQL` APIs via HTTP.

See below diagram(Connected mode)

[image]

**Server-side rendering-** on the other hand, renders the components(`React`) on the server. The output is HTML content.

The application is server-side rendered (SSR) by the Sitecore instance, meaning complete HTML is delivered to the user without any ***initial*** JS execution on the client.

This mode ***allows*** your Sitecore users to manage content, presentation and other marketing features for your JSS app using Sitecore's `Experience Editor`.

Rendering performed by server (SSR by Node instances orchestrated by Sitecore)
Data comes from Sitecore `LayoutService`, passed from Sitecore to Node with no extra HTTP call.

Via Sitecore configuration files, you can configure the `Node.js` instance used for server-side rendering.

Usage: Content Management/Authoring server, production Content Delivery server (if not using headless hosting).

See below diagram(Integrated mode).

[image]

**Reference:** https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/application-modes